# Spring Data Jpa, REST, org.springframework.beans .TypeMismatchException from Angularjs front end

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I have request from my Angularjs factory is as follows:

```
 .factory('TrackingNumberDetailsUpsGeneralService', function ($http) {
        return {           
            findByInvoiceDetailsId: function (invoiceDetails) {  
                console.log("invoiceDetails  " + invoiceDetails.id);  
                return $http.get('/api/trackingNumberDetailsUpss/byInvoiceDetailsId', {params: {invoiceDetailsId : invoiceDetails.id}}).then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

And in my Tracking...Resource.java, I have

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/trackingNumberDetailsUpss/byInvoiceDetailsId/",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    public List<TrackingNumberDetailsUps> findByInvoiceDetailsId(@RequestParam(value="invoiceDetailsId") Long invoiceDetailsId,
            @RequestParam(value = "page" , required = false) Integer offset,
            @RequestParam(value = "per_page", required = false) Integer limit) {
        log.debug("REST request to get TrackingNumberDetailsUps  By Invoice Details Id " + invoiceDetailsId);
        return trackingNumberDetailsUpsService.findByInvoiceDetailsId(invoiceDetailsId);
    }
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/trackingNumberDetailsUpss/byInvoiceDetailsId?cacheBuster=1444014377012&invoiceDetailsId=2 400 Bad Request

{"timestamp":1444015194707,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.beans
.TypeMismatchException","message":"Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
 'java.lang.Long'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"byInvoiceDetailsId
\"","path":"/api/trackingNumberDetailsUpss/byInvoiceDetailsId"}
```

I am not able to figure out where is the problem. Can any one help me in resolving this.

The following is my Request :

```
 .factory('TrackingNumberDetailsUpsGeneralService', function ($http) {
        return {           
            findByInvoiceDetailsId: function (invoiceDetails) {  
                console.log("invoiceDetails  " + invoiceDetails.id);  
                return $http.get('/api/trackingNumberDetailsUpss/byInvoiceDetailsId', {params: {invoiceDetailsId : invoiceDetails.id}}).then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: Can you please post the request you actually send from your client?

Comment: I have edited the question with the request from client.

Comment: Try removing the extra `/` from the end of your @RequestMapping annotation. It does matter - just tested.

Comment: Yes, you are right, that slash solved the problem. You can post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the extra `/` from the end of your `@RequestMapping` annotation.

It does matter - just tested.